# Why do you initialize Vector2 variables to "Vector2.Zero"?

Tags: c#, xna

Sorry I'm new to XNA and C# and I see in tutorials that they initialize their Vector2 variables to Vector2.Zero as soon as they're declared. However there doesn't seem to be any difference when I don't set it to Vector2.Zero and instead I put:

```
Vector2 vector;
```

And in the constructor method:

```
vector = new Vector2(4,4);
```

Can someone enlighten me on what difference it makes? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Vector2` is a struct. This means that a property or field of that type cannot be set to `NULL` and therefore will be initialized to a default value.

I suspect your code `Vector2 vector;` will actually be compiled to `Vector2 vector = default(Vector2)` which I think will be equal to `Vector2.Zero`.

Comment: So does that mean regardless of whether Vector2.Zero is added, the value will be set by default to the equivalent of Vector2.Zero?
Why do they initialize it to Vector2.Zero then if it will be done by default anyway?

Comment: @user3451948 - Readability/maintainability, possibly. It makes it glaringly obvious that it's been initialized, and what it was initialized to.

Comment: As Steve says, if you want to declare a vector of magnitude zero, `Vector2 vector;` is correct; `Vector2 vector = Vector2.Zero;` is __obviously__ correct _and intentional_.